# lost in assembly NASM ELF64 world

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, nasm

So as part of my Computer Architecture class I need to get comfortable with Assembly, or at least comfortable enough, I'm trying to read the input to the user and then reprint it (for the time being), this is my how I tried to laid this out in pseudo code:

1. Declare msg variable (this will be printed on screen)
2. Declare length variable (to be used by the sys_write function) with long enough value
3. Pop the stack once to get the program name
4. Pop the stack again to get the first argument
5. Move the current value of the stack into the msg variable
6. Move msg to ECX (sys_write argument)
7. Mov length to EDX (sys_write argument)
8. Call sys_write using standard output
9. Kernel call
10. Call sys_exit and leave

This is my code so far

```
section .data
  msg:    db 'placeholder text',0xa;
  length: dw 0x123;

section .text
  global _start 

    _start: 
      pop rbx;
      pop rbx;
      ; this is not working when I leave it in I get this error:
      ; invalid combination of opcode and operands                                                                                            
      ;mov msg, rbx;
      mov ecx, msg;
      mov edx, length;

      mov eax, 4;
      mov ebx, 1;
      int 0x80;
      mov ebx, 0;
      mov eax, 1;
      int 0x80;
```

When I leave it out (not moving the argument into msg), I get this output

```
placeholder text
#.shstrtab.text.data
                     �@�$�`��
```

We really just begun with NASM so ANY help will be greatly appreciated, I've been looking at this http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~if817/arquivos/asmtut/index.html#stack and http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/ adapting the examples adapting the registry names to the best of my understanding to match http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo11.html

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, 64bit compiling (not even sure if this is the right word) NASM under ELF64, I'm sorry to ask such a silly question but I have been unable to find an easy enough tutorial for NASM that uses 64bits.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking (is there really a question in there somewhere?), but the length you write is `0x123`, which is far longer than the actual text. That's why you get lots of extra text in the output.

Comment: Some examples here that might help: http://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=912.0 Other examples nearby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the program is called the stack should looks like this:

```
+----------------+
| ...            | <--- rsp + 24
+----------------+
| argument 2     | <--- rsp + 16
+----------------+
| argument 1     | <--- rsp + 8
+----------------+
| argument count | <--- rsp
+----------------+
```

The first argument is the name of your program and the second is the user input (if the user typed anything as an argument). So the count of the arguments is at least 1.

The arguments for system calls in 64-mode are stored in the following registers:

- rax (system call number)
- rdi (1st argument)
- rsi (2nd argument)
- rdx (3rd argument)
- rcx (4th argument)
- r8 (5th argument)
- r9 (6th argument)

And the system call is called with `syscall`. The numbers of all the system calls can be found <s>[here](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/linux_syscalls_64bit.html)</s> [here](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) (yes they are different from the numbers in 32 bit mode).

This is the program which should do your stuff:

```
section .data
    msg:    db 'Requesting 1 argument!', 10  ; message + newline

section .text
    global  _start

_start:
    cmp     qword [rsp], 2    ; check if argument count is 2
    jne     fail              ; if not jump to the fail lable

    mov     rax, 1            ; sys_write
    mov     rdi, 1            ; stdout
    mov     rsi, [rsp+16]     ; get the address of the argument 
    mov     rdx, 1            ; one character (length 1)

loop:
    cmp     byte [rsi], 0     ; check if current character is 0
    je      exit              ; if 0 then jump to the exit lable
    syscall
    inc     rsi               ; jump to the next character
    jmp     loop              ; repeat

fail:
    mov     rax, 1            ; sys_write
    mov     rdi, 1            ; stdout
    lea     rsi, [rel msg]    ; move the address of the lable msg in rsi
    mov     rdx, 23           ; length = 23
    syscall

exit:
    mov     rax, 60           ; sys_exit
    mov     rdi, 0            ; with code 0
    syscall
```

Since the code isn't prefect in many ways you may want to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

You've followed the instructions quite literally -- and this is expected output.

The stack variable that you write to the message, is just some binary value -- to be exact, it's a pointer to an array of strings containing the command line arguments.
To make sense of that, either you would have to print those strings, or convert the pointer to ascii string eg. "0x12313132".

Comment: I see okay, I will reduce the length of my sys_write calls in the future to avoid this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My OS is Ubuntu 64-bit.   Compiling your code produced the error:

```
nasm print3.asm 

print3.asm:12: error: instruction not supported in 16-bit mode
print3.asm:13: error: instruction not supported in 16-bit mode
```

Exactly where the "pop rbx" is located.

Adding "BITS 64" to the top of the asm file solved the problem:

```
BITS 64

section .data
  msg:    db 'placeholder text',0xa;
  length: dw 0x123;

...
```